# Add a "show all function" to letter sorted sitemap

Tags: php, sitemap

This is my sitemap: http://webmaster.fniffi.de/sitemap/H/de.html

It's sorted by letters and I'd like to add a button to show all FAQ entries in one list. Or just change it to show all FAQ entries instantly. I don't need the letter sort function. Can anyone assist me in creating such a function. I am a complete PHP noob.

This is my code:

```
<?php


if (!defined('IS_VALID_PHPMYFAQ')) {
exit();
}


class PMF_Sitemap
{
private $_config;

private $type = '';
private $user = -1;
private $groups = array();


 private $groupSupport = false;

 public function __construct(PMF_Configuration $config)
{
    $this->_config = $config;

    if ($this->_config->get('security.permLevel') == 'medium') {
        $this->groupSupport = true;
    }
}

/**
 * @param integer $userId
 */
public function setUser($userId = -1)
{
    $this->user = $userId;
}

/**
 * @param array $groups
 */
public function setGroups(Array $groups)
{
    $this->groups = $groups;
}

/**
 * Returns all available first letters
 *
 * @return array
 * @since  2007-03-30
 * @author Thorsten Rinne <thorsten@phpmyfaq.de>
 */
public function getAllFirstLetters()
{
    global $sids;

    if ($this->groupSupport) {
        $permPart = sprintf("( fdg.group_id IN (%s)
        OR
            (fdu.user_id = %d AND fdg.group_id IN (%s)))",
            implode(', ', $this->groups),
            $this->user,
            implode(', ', $this->groups));
    } else {
        $permPart = sprintf("( fdu.user_id = %d OR fdu.user_id = -1 )",
            $this->user);
    }

    $writeLetters = '<ul class="nav">';

    if ($this->_config->getDb() instanceof PMF_DB_Sqlite || $this->_config->getDb() instanceof PMF_DB_Sqlite3) {

        $query = sprintf("
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT UPPER(SUBSTR(fd.thema, 1, 1)) AS letters
                FROM
                    %sfaqdata fd
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_group AS fdg
                ON
                    fd.id = fdg.record_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_user AS fdu
                ON
                    fd.id = fdu.record_id
                WHERE
                    fd.lang = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.active = 'yes'
                AND
                    %s
                ORDER BY
                    letters",
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            $this->_config->getLanguage()->getLanguage(),
            $permPart
        );
    } else {

        $query = sprintf("
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT UPPER(SUBSTRING(fd.thema, 1, 1)) AS letters
                FROM
                    %sfaqdata fd
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_group AS fdg
                ON
                    fd.id = fdg.record_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_user AS fdu
                ON
                    fd.id = fdu.record_id
                WHERE
                    fd.lang = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.active = 'yes'
                AND
                    %s
                ORDER BY
                    letters",
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
            $this->_config->getLanguage()->getLanguage(),
            $permPart
        );
    }

    $result = $this->_config->getDb()->query($query);
    while ($row = $this->_config->getDb()->fetchObject($result)) {
        $letters = PMF_String::strtoupper($row->letters);
        if (PMF_String::preg_match("/^[一-龠]+|[ぁ-ん]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]/i", $letters)) {
            $url = sprintf(
                '%s?%saction=sitemap&amp;letter=%s&amp;lang=%s',
                PMF_Link::getSystemRelativeUri(),
                $sids,
                $letters,
                $this->_config->getLanguage()->getLanguage());
            $oLink         = new PMF_Link($url, $this->_config);
            $oLink->text   = (string)$letters;
            $writeLetters .= '<li>' . $oLink->toHtmlAnchor().'</li>';
        }
    }
    $writeLetters .= '</ul>';

    return $writeLetters;
}

/**
 * Returns all records from the current first letter
 *
 * @param  string $letter Letter
 * @return array
 * @since  2007-03-30
 * @author Thorsten Rinne <thorsten@phpmyfaq.de>
 */
public function getRecordsFromLetter($letter = 'A')
{
    global $sids, $PMF_LANG;

    if ($this->groupSupport) {
        $permPart = sprintf("( fdg.group_id IN (%s)
        OR
            (fdu.user_id = %d AND fdg.group_id IN (%s)))",
            implode(', ', $this->groups),
            $this->user,
            implode(', ', $this->groups));
    } else {
        $permPart = sprintf("( fdu.user_id = %d OR fdu.user_id = -1 )",
            $this->user);
    }

    $letter = PMF_String::strtoupper($this->_config->getDb()->escape(PMF_String::substr($letter, 0, 1)));

    $writeMap = '';

    switch($this->type) {
        case 'db2':
        case 'sqlite':
            $query = sprintf("
                SELECT
                    fd.thema AS thema,
                    fd.id AS id,
                    fd.lang AS lang,
                    fcr.category_id AS category_id,
                    fd.content AS snap
                FROM
                    %sfaqcategoryrelations fcr,
                    %sfaqdata fd
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_group AS fdg
                ON
                    fd.id = fdg.record_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_user AS fdu
                ON
                    fd.id = fdu.record_id
                WHERE
                    fd.id = fcr.record_id
                AND
                    SUBSTR(fd.thema, 1, 1) = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.lang = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.active = 'yes'
                AND
                    %s",
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                $letter,
                $this->_config->getLanguage()->getLanguage(),
                $permPart);
            break;

        default:
            $query = sprintf("
                SELECT
                    fd.thema AS thema,
                    fd.id AS id,
                    fd.lang AS lang,
                    fcr.category_id AS category_id,
                    fd.content AS snap
                FROM
                    %sfaqcategoryrelations fcr,
                    %sfaqdata fd
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_group AS fdg
                ON
                    fd.id = fdg.record_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    %sfaqdata_user AS fdu
                ON
                    fd.id = fdu.record_id
                WHERE
                    fd.id = fcr.record_id
                AND
                    SUBSTRING(fd.thema, 1, 1) = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.lang = '%s'
                AND
                    fd.active = 'yes'
                AND
                    %s",
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                PMF_Db::getTablePrefix(),
                $letter,
                $this->_config->getLanguage()->getLanguage(),
                $permPart);
            break;
    }

    $result = $this->_config->getDb()->query($query);
    $oldId = 0;
    while ($row = $this->_config->getDb()->fetchObject($result)) {
        if ($oldId != $row->id) {
            $title = PMF_String::htmlspecialchars($row->thema, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
            $url   = sprintf(
                '%s?%saction=artikel&amp;cat=%d&amp;id=%d&amp;artlang=%s',
                PMF_Link::getSystemRelativeUri(),
                $sids,
                $row->category_id,
                $row->id,
                $row->lang
            );

            $oLink            = new PMF_Link($url, $this->_config);
            $oLink->itemTitle = $row->thema;
            $oLink->text      = $title;
            $oLink->tooltip   = $title;

            $writeMap .= '<li>'.$oLink->toHtmlAnchor().'<br />'."\n";
            $writeMap .= PMF_Utils::chopString(strip_tags($row->snap), 25). " ...</li>\n";
        }
        $oldId = $row->id;
    }

    $writeMap = empty($writeMap) ? '' : '<ul>' . $writeMap . '</ul>';

    return $writeMap;
}
}
```

Comment: Why have a different page load  for each letter when it seems like you only have a handful of pages?  Why not just load entire sitemap and use javascript to hide/display/navigate relevent portions?

Comment: That's what I am asking for. I don't know how to do this